# Redirect user and return JSON in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to redirect a user to a different page/view and return a JSON result?  I have a web application that makes a cross-domain call to another method on another asp.net mvc web app and I want to redirect the user to another page/view after they make the call, but I also want to return a JSON string to the calling web app indicating that the user was redirecting successfully or there was an error.  How can I handle this scenario?

Is this something I can do in one method or does it need to be split up? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all that you need for basic scenario:

```
$.ajax {
  ..
  ..
  ..
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.message_for_user);
    // redirect from client
    window.location.replace(data.url_to_redirect);
    // or make another request to your server and redirect directly from server
    makeRequestToRedirectController(data.some_message_for_server)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have three systems interacting here:

- Client (HTML/JavaScript)
- Server (ASP.NET)
- Remote Server (technology used is immaterial)

And if I still understand correctly, the scenario is that Client is making a request to Remote Server, but Server needs to know the result of that request?

Since the request is between Client and Remote Server, Server isn't involved and can't directly receive a response from Remote Server.  But Client can handle this interaction.  One approach might be something like:

- Client makes request to Remote Server
- Client receives response from Remote Server, indicating either an error or to perform a redirect
- If an error, Client notifies Server of the error (and probably notifies the user as well)
- If a redirect, Client notifies Server of the success and then performs the redirect.

In mostly pseudo-code, that might end up looking something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://remoteserver/request_target'
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // success, notify Server and redirect
    $.post('http://server/success_handler', successData)
     .done(function () {
        window.location.replace('http://remoteserver/redirect_target');
    });

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    // fail, notify Server
    $.post('http://server/error_handler', errorData);

});
```

So first it's performing an AJAX request to Remote Server.  If the request succeeds, it then performs an AJAX request to Server to notify of the success and then, after that request, performs the redirect.  If the request to Remote Server fails, if performs an AJAX request to Server to notify of the error.  (What goes in `successData` or `errorData`, if anything at all, is up to whatever you need to send to Server.)

Comment: Never use it like this `window.location.href = 'http://remoteserver/redirect_target';` It's the most bad thing that you to advice..

Comment: There are only two systems here, the calling client and the client being called, both are web applications.

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov - Can you provide a reason why not to use `windows.location.href` instead of just saying not to?

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov: I've updated to `window.location = ...` instead then.  But can you provide information about this?  I've used both without problems.

Comment: @xaisoft: If there are only two systems in play here, then it's not clear to me what the issue is.  This statement seems to indicate that there are two servers: `"I have a web application that makes a cross-domain call to another method on another asp.net mvc web app"`.  Beyond that, there is of course the client.  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: If shortly, than history will not be saved if you use any method other than `window.location.replace()`. Here is good question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript.

Comment: I vote up your answer, good, but a little over-complicated for me :)

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov: Fair enough, I've updated accordingly.  Though "It's the most bad thing that you can advise [sic]" is a bit overreaching, given that the top answer on your reference question includes it as an option.  It's not a "redirect" in the strictest sense, so you're right in that it's not the correct method here.  But it's hardly harmful overall, and has perfectly valid uses.

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov: This approach may indeed be over-complicated depending on the actual issue, but the OP has yet to clarify what the actual problem is.  He stated that he's making a request to a completely different server, but then in a comment on this answer indicated that he isn't making a request to a different server.  It's not clear to me what the issue is at all here.

Comment: Yes i understand, i give him an idea in my answer, that similar to your but without to much details. I don't think he need parameters `textStatus, jqXHR` and this handler `fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. And my basic scratch enough to understand the approach for problem. Also i think he can successfully transfer result in the parameter without to much handlers like this `http://server/success_handler` and `http://server/error_handler`, but it just my vision so don't take this in mind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40514/discussion-between-alex-v-kostyukov-and-david)